# How to take a single piece of data from a YQL query result

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, yql

I made an xcode project in which I logged the JSON from a YQL query. This is the output I get:

```
    quote =     {
AverageDailyVolume = 22235800;
Change = "+0.03";
DaysHigh = "36.60";
DaysLow = "35.55";
DaysRange = "35.55 - 36.60";
LastTradePriceOnly = "36.38";
MarketCapitalization = "37.523B";
Name = "Yahoo! Inc.";
StockExchange = NasdaqNM;
Symbol = YHOO;
Volume = 28937796;
YearHigh = "41.72";
YearLow = "23.47";
symbol = YHOO;
```

};

}

What i want to do is take a single line from this code. for example: "LastTradePriceOnly ="36.38"". Then i want to be able to store the value of LastTradePriceOnly (36.38) in a NSNumber/NSInteger.

the code i have in my project is mainly:

```
- (IBAction)enterButton2:(id)sender {
NSString *query2 = (self.queryText2.text);
NSDictionary *results2 = [yql query:query2];
NSString *respond2 = [[results2 valueForKeyPath:@"query.results"]description];
self.resultView2.text = respond2;
NSLog(@"%@",respond2);}
```

the query i used is placed in a textView, the query is :

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ("YHOO")
```

thanks to @Larme i tried to use this method:

```
[[yourObject objectForKey:@"quote"] objectForKey:@"LastTradePriceOnly"]
```

but i couldnt get it to work.

help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's exactly the log shown? `respond2`? Could you show the line you log?

Comment: @Larme the NSLog(@"respond2"); logs the JSON i included in the beginning of my question.

Comment: Ok, so you put your response (respond2) into an `NSString`. That's quite strange. Try replacing `yourObject` (from the code I gave your earlier) with `[results2 valueForKeyPath:@"query.results"]` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:
Ok, so you put your response (`respond2`) into an `NSString`. That's quite strange. Let's restart from something that was a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`: `[results2 valueForKeyPath:@"query.results"]`:

```
[[[results2 valueForKeyPath:@"query.results"] objectForKey:@"quote"] objectForKey:@"LastTradePriceOnly"];
```